# What is the technical term for these speakers?

Tags: speakers, terminology

What is the technical term for this style of speaker?

In my experience they are typically 3-5 feet tall, and 12 to 24 inches wide.  Usually has 1 woofer, 1 midrange, and 1 tweeter.

[image: Yamaha Speakers]
[image: JBL Speakers]
[image: Other Speaker]
[image: More Speakers]

Comment: well floor standing speakers it is... in Speaker world we talk more about inches, tweeters, 2-3 way , passive/active, rather than the actual speaker. I mean dimensions are kind of "less important" . other than that if the speaker is standing on the ground it's a floor standing speaker.

Comment: Well, when I google 'floor standing speaker' I get these tall thin ones with no low end.

Comment: ok google 3 way speaker , or go with 2 way 10 inch speaker, or big hi fi speaker .. it's really a matter of description when you are searching without a brand/ model reference..

Comment: So there's no technical term for this style?  Post it as an answer and get +25.

Comment: nah , not really an answer :D you could even search with the picture in google :D glad i helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common names for such kind of models are **3-Way Classic**, **3W Classic** or simply **"3-Ways"**.

*Troels Gravesen*, a danish DIY speaker pioneer, has a page all dedicated to that design: http://www.troelsgravesen.dk/3WClassic.htm.

On his website you can find other variants of the design (and other interesting designs): http://www.troelsgravesen.dk/Diy_Loudspeaker_Projects.htm